# How can I use Smart::Comments in a module I load without changing its source?

Tags: perl, command-line, module

How can I specify that Smart::Comments be loaded for my original script, as well as for any of the modules it directly loads. However, since it is a source-filter, it would probably wreck havoc if applied to every module loaded by every other loaded module.

For example, my script includes

```
use Neu::Image;
```

I would like to load [`Smart::Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Smart::Comments) for `Neu::Image` as well, but specifying

```
$ perl -MSmart::Comments script.pl
```

does not load `Smart::Comments` for `Neu::Image`.

This behavior is described in the [Smart::Comments documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Smart::Comments):

> If you're debugging an application you
>   can also invoke it with the module
>   from the command-line:
>
> ```
> perl -MSmart::Comments $application.pl
> ```
>
> Of course, this only enables smart
>   comments in the application file
>   itself, not in any modules that the
>   application loads.

A few other things that I've looked at already:

- [Perl Command-Line Options](http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2004/08/09/commandline.html?page=1)
- [perldoc perlrun](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlrun) (I searched it
  for the word "module")

**WORKAROUND**
As gbacon mentions, Smart::Comments provides an environment variable option that would allow turning it on or off. However, I would like to be able to turn it on without modifying the original source, if possible.

Comment: “Some men aren't looking for anything logical. They can't be bought, bullied, reasoned, or negotiated with. Some men just wanna watch the world burn.”

Comment: @gbacon: Are you referring to my use of Smart::Comments? I'm just trying to find a way to play with fire "safely." ;)

Comment: Is your question really "How can I use Smart::Comments in every module I load without changing their source"?

Comment: @brian Actually, yes. Is that possible without causing the "world to burn"?

Comment: Why don't you want to want to change the source? Are you in a situation where you aren't allowed?

Comment: Well, you asked for it. Answer updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You almost certainly want to add `use Smart::Comments` to modules that contain such and then [flip the switch in your environment](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Smart-Comments-1.0.4/lib/Smart/Comments.pm#CONFIGURATION_AND_ENVIRONMENT) by setting `$Smart_Comments` appropriately.

Stash-munging, `import`-hijacking monkey-patching is madness.

But maybe you're into that sort of thing. Say you have `Foo.pm`:

```
package Foo;

use Exporter 'import';
our @EXPORT = qw/ foo /;

#use Smart::Comments;

sub foo {
  my @result;
  for (my $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    ### $i
    push @result => $i if $i % 2 == 0;
  }
  wantarray ? @result : \@result;
}

1;
```

Ordinary usage:

```
$ perl -MFoo -e 'print foo, "\n"'
024
```

Ordinary is dull and boring, of course. With `run-foo`, we take bold, dashing steps!

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

BEGIN {
  unshift @INC => \&inject_smart_comments;

  my %direct;
  open my $fh, "<", $0 or die "$0: open: $!";
  while (<$fh>) {
    ++$direct{$1} if /^\s*use\s+([A-Z][:\w]*)/;
  }
  close $fh;

  sub inject_smart_comments {
    my(undef,$path) = @_;
    s/[\/\\]/::/g, s/\.pm$// for my $mod = $path;
    if ($direct{$mod}) {
      open my $fh, "<", $path or die "$0: open $path: $!";
      return sub {
        return 0 unless defined($_ = <$fh>);
        s{^(\s*package\s+[A-Z][:\w]*\s*;\s*)$}
         {$1 use Smart::Comments;\n};
        return 1;
      };
    }
  }
}

use Foo;

print foo, "\n";
```

(Please pardon the compactness: I shrunk it so it would all fit in an unscrolled block.)

Output:

```
$ ./run-foo

### $i: 0

### $i: 1

### $i: 2

### $i: 3

### $i: 4
024
```

¡Viva!

With [`@INC` hooks](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) we can substitute our own or modified sources. The code watches for attempts to `require` modules directly used by the program. On a hit, `inject_smart_comments` returns an iterator that yields one line at a time. When this crafty, artful iterator sees the package declaration, it appends an innocent-looking `use Smart::Comments` to the chunk, making it appear as though it were in the module's source all along.

By trying to parse Perl code with regular expressions, the code will break if the package declaration isn't on a line by itself, for example. Season to taste.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the environment switch.

Comment: Wow! I mean, WOW! Kudos to gbacon, the Perl Master!

Comment: Thanks for the references to @INC hooks. I really didn't want to ask for you or anyone else to do a lot of work. I thought there might be something simpler. Wow, that is some awesome magic!

Comment: Bug: the module has to be in the current directory. As written, it won't search `@INC`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like this idea makes any sense.  If you are utilizing [`Smart::Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Smart%3a%3aComments) in a module, why would you not want to `use Smart::Comments` in that module's source?  Even if you could get [`Smart::Comments`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Smart%3a%3aComments) to apply to all modules loaded in a script via `-M`, it probably wouldn't be a good idea because:

- You're obfuscating the fact that your modules are using smart comments by *not* including the `use` line in their source.
- You could potentially introduce bizarre behavior from modules you `use` in your script which happen to have what look like smart comments, but aren't really.  If a module doesn't contain smart comments, you should not force them down its throat.

As [gbacon said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156943/how-can-i-use-smartcomments-in-every-module-i-load-without-changing-their-sourc/2157492#2157492), the right way to do this is to `use` the module in each of your modules that make use of it, and then suppress them with an environment variable when you don't want the output.

Also as he said, it's still probably possible to do this with some "Stash-munging, import-hijacking monkey-patching" madness, but that's a lot of work.  I don't think anyone is going to put the effort into giving you a solution along those lines when it is not a good idea in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me Smart::Comments are only for debugging. From brian's comments I was starting to think that there was another way to do it that wasn't so complicated. I wouldn't ask for anyone to go through a lot of effort.